# Angular design question - referencing control vs code duplication

Tags: angular

I am looking for a way to design global error reporting for my Angular 14-15 application.

Think of having an angular app with many pages and many components that at the moment has no error handling logic. I want to now add error handling logic in such a way that **if in the future it changes** from say popping up a tooltip with error message **to something completely different and yet undefined** (may be the input will not be involved at all), **I would not need to change every page and every component**. I would only change the  error handling logic.

Say my first error handling logic is - identify the input (if any) involved in the error, make its border red and when user triggers mousever event on that red input they see a tooltip with the error message.
And let's say a month from now I get a new requirement that instead of tooltip, error messages are to be shown in a scrollable table that can be seen when clicking a special "error log" icon at the top right corner of the app.
My goal is to design my error handling in such a way that the switch from first error handling logic to second error handling logic (or any other third) would not involve changing any of the components and pages where the inputs are defined. But only changing the error handling logic.

I suspect this is not how you would do it in Angular, but here is an idea I have in my mind:
In my example.ts file of each component where I receive the error message, I then call something like

```
reportMyError(errMessage, input)
```

where input is an **optional** parameter and represents the component of some input type (for example <input type='text'...) and inside reportMyError I would be able to manipulate DOM enough to make input change style and add a tooltip or some other element that is not initially defined in my example.html file

Answer (score 0):

Angular already has its own global [`ErrorHandler`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/packages/core/src/error_handler.ts) as part of its core package that works by default to log errors in console on happening.

```
/**
 * Provides a hook for centralized exception handling.
 * The default implementation of `ErrorHandler` prints error messages to the `console`. To intercept error handling, write a custom exception handler that replaces this default as appropriate for your app.
 *
 * @usageNotes
 * ### Example
 * class MyErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
 *   handleError(error) {
 *     // do something with the exception
 *   }
 * }
 *
 * @NgModule({
 *   providers: [{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: MyErrorHandler}]
 * })
 * class MyModule {}
 */
export class ErrorHandler {
  _console: Console = console;

  handleError(error: any): void {
    const originalError = this._findOriginalError(error);

    this._console.error('ERROR', error);
    if (originalError) {
      this._console.error('ORIGINAL ERROR', originalError);
    }
  }

  _findOriginalError(error: any): Error|null {
    let e = error && getOriginalError(error);
    while (e && getOriginalError(e)) {
      e = getOriginalError(e);
    }

    return e || null;
  }
}
```

Of course you can override it to display and handle errors the way you want (e.g., routing to different page)

For example:

```
import { ErrorHandler, Injectable} from '@angular/core';
 
@Injectable()
export class MyErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
    handleError(error) {
       console.error('An error occurred:', error.message);
       console.error(error);
       alert(error);   // using browser alert or however you want to display it
   }
}
```

Another example using [`MatSnackBar`](https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/overview)

```
import { ErrorHandler, Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
 
@Injectable()
export class MyErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

    constructor(private snackBar: MatSnackBar) {}

    handleError(error) {
       this.snackBar.open(error.message);
   }
}
```

You will need to add it to list of providers for Angular module based applications like below

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: MyErrorHandler },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And for Angular standalone based applications (Angular v14 and beyond)

```
// In main.ts
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: MyErrorHandler },
  ]
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but I believe you are missing the jist of the question, it's about designing a system where a component similar to snackbar or a tooltip  does not  get "declared" beside each input on each page , but instead can be used in a generic way and be dynamically overlayed beside the input that is passed as a parameter to say handleError. May be try reading the question again

Comment: If i got what you want right, then maybe you just need to define your own input `@Component` that has its own error handling mechanism, or add that logic to a  `@Directive`, but you use it with HTML `input` elements. Something like `matInput` directive https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview. You can find its source here
https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/material/input/input.ts

Comment: You mean create a custom directive? like say errHandler and then use it like <my-input  [(errHandler)]=input1Err ...> and inside errHandler it will not just add red border to that input when input1Err is assigned smething but also inject a tooltip like component into the DOM? I don't have any experience with custom directives, but brief look up says they are EITHER structural OR attribute (not both at the same time). And it seems mine would need to be both since it changes the element styling (attribute) and also changes the DOM structure by injecting a tooltip that was not there (structural).

Comment: I mean either create your own custom component input `<my-input />` that has its own error handling logic, or create your own custom directive `myInput` that also has error handling logic for its associated `input`, and use it with HTML input like `<input myInput />` similar to `<input matInput />` that i put its src

Comment: @ILIABROUDNO can you please check the examples in this link
https://medium.com/hackernoon/create-reuseable-validation-directive-in-angualr-2-dcb0b0df2ce8

Comment: Hi @fujy, in your example for a custom directive the end result still has all the things I said in my question I am trying to avoid: The error handling being intimately linked to the HTML.

Comment: @ILIABROUDNO Did you check the `SnackBar` solution?
https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/overview

Comment: Hi @fujy, I did look carefully at all your answers and links and you are really REALLY missing the point. I rephrased my question in hopes that it is clearer, but I think the problem is not the clarity, but the modern phenomenon of nobody wanting to read more than 2 lines of text (I'm  often guilty of it myself)

Comment: @ILIABROUDNO, I read everything that you wrote, and I don't really see how writing your own customized reusable component or directive that has your initial error handling mechanism of manipulating DOM and adding a tooltip (as per your saying), and reuse it whenever you want, change it later when requirement changes without having to change every component that uses it, I don't really see how this suggestion doesn't fix your problem ... good luck